# Única instância de Classe C#

Tags: c#, winforms, classes, singleton

Tenho um Windows Form com o seguinte código:

```
public partial class frmCadastroPessoaFisica : Form
{
    public frmCadastroPessoaFisica()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Gostaria de criar somente uma instância deste form.

Algumas respostas sobre o assunto no stackoverflow em inglês dizem para usar o padrão singleton:

```
public class Singleton
{
    private static Singleton instance;

    private Singleton() { }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                lock (typeof(Singleton))
                    if (instance == null) instance = new Singleton();

            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

fonte: linhadecodigo.com.br

Já outras dizem que usar o singleton para isso seria exagero.

Qual a forma correta de permitir somente uma instância deste form?

Comment: Minha dúvida é no caso de forms ou classes do tipo GUI, acredito que esta pergunta que foi citada é mais no sentido amplo e genérico.

Comment: Tudo bem, obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Só veja direitinho se vc realmente precisa de um `form` inteiro persistido, ou apenas os dados que o preenche.

Comment: Eu considero o Singleton um antipattern hoje em dia, mas acho que em certas situações não vale a pena adicionar uma técnica de DI e controle para garantir esses problemas... então se for uma solução funcional e que não causa tantos transtornos, aqui fica um link ótimo explicando diversas maneiras de implementar o Singleton e a vantagem/desvantagem de cada uma: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi é somente o form, a aplicação é grande e o form pode ser "chamado" de vários lugares, porem somente uma instância dele pode existir por vez.

Comment: Singleton pattern é considerado ruim: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/137975/what-is-so-bad-about-singletons

Answer (score 6):

Existem várias maneiras de guarantir que apenas uma instância de sua classe seja invocada. O seu exemplo contém uma delas, chamada *singleton factory*.

Uma outra possibilidade é via definição estática, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
public static class Instances
{
    public static frmCadastroPessoaFisica frmCadastroPessoaFisica;

    static Instances()
    {
        frmCadastroPessoaFisica = new frmCadastroPessoaFisica();
    }
}
```

Você poderá acessar a instância estática via `Instances.frmCadastroPessoaFisica`.

Comment: Não havia pensado nisso, vou fazer um teste aqui.

Comment: Se for para criar estaticamente, acho que poderia iniciar o valor da variável na própria definição dela. Só lembrando que dessas maneiras a criação do form é sempre efetuada, mesmo quando ele não for usada...

Comment: @GabrielKatakura Na verdade a instância é criada quando mencionada pela primeira vez no código, Gabriel. Sinta-se à vontade para testar.